# Embed a React component into a HTML site, without affecting the parent site's styling and without an iframe

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, iframe

I have a React component that I want to build and insert into an HTML site. The component has some styling, which if imported will conflict with the HTML site's styling. I have a limitation that does not allow me to use an iframe. Does anyone know of any solutions that will allow me to scope the React component's css to only that component?

Comment: I also have the same problem.  Did you find solutions to this?

Comment: @gsy unfortunately, I had to resort to using an iFrame. The other option was to obfuscate the css classes of my component and insert them into the other page, but there's no guarantee that it won't conflict with the parent site's css.